# Displaying Images from Sd Card but taking time in android

Tags: android

Hi in the below I am displaying images from sdcard.sdcard means storing into locally.but while privew the images it was showing some black color after image got displaying.

want to display smooth preview with black screen.i am unable to figure out the issue.can any one help me.

**java**

```
public class ImageGallery extends Activity {

    Bundle bundle;
    String catid, temp, responseJson;
    JSONObject json;
    ImageView imageViewPager;
    // for parsing
    JSONObject o1, o2;
    JSONArray a1, a2;
    int k;
    Boolean toggleTopBar;
    ArrayList<String> imageThumbnails;
    ArrayList<String> imageFull;
    public static int imagePosition=0;
    SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView, imageViewPreview, fullImage ;
    ImageView thumb1,  back;
    private  LinearLayout thumb2;
    RelativeLayout topLayout, stripeView;
    RelativeLayout thumbnailButtons;
    FrameLayout gridFrame;

    //SharedPreferences data
    SharedPreferences s1;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    int swipeCounter;
    ParsingForFinalImages parsingObject;
int position_grid;
    SharedPreferences p;

    Bitmap bm;
    int numOfImagesInsidee;
    LinearLayout backLinLayout;
    public static boolean isThumb2=false;
    public static boolean isThumb1=false;

public static ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);
        //isThumb2=false;
        toggleTopBar = false;
        //position_grid=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");


        thumbnailButtons = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.thumbnailButtons);
        topLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.topLayout);
        //fullImage = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(R.id.fullimage);

        backLinLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lin_back);
        backLinLayout.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Intent io = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        // clear the previous activity and start a new task
                        // System.gc();
                        // io.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(io);
                        finish();

                    }

                });

        ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getBaseContext());
        Boolean isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();



        thumb1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.thumb1);
        thumb2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.thumb2);
        stripeView = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.stripeView) ;
        gridFrame = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.gridFrame);


        thumb1.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        stripeView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        gridFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        viewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //fullImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        thumb1.setClickable(false);
                        isThumb1=true;
isThumb2=false;
                        Log.i("Thumb Position 1",""+ImageGallery.imagePosition);
                        viewPager.removeAllViews();
                        Fragment newFragment = new GridFragment2();
                        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft.replace(R.id.gridFrame, newFragment).commit();


                    }

                });
        thumb2.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {


                        // stripeView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        stripeView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        gridFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        viewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                       // fullImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        thumb1.setClickable(true);
                        isThumb2=true;
                        isThumb1=false;
                        Log.i("Thumb Position 2",""+ImageGallery.imagePosition);
                        viewPager.removeAllViews();
                        Fragment newFragment = new ImageStripeFragment();
                        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft.replace(R.id.gridFrame, newFragment).commit();

                    }
                });




        // allow networking on main thread
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        /*bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        catid = bundle.getString("catid");*/
        // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), catid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        // making json using the catalogue id we got

        p = getSharedPreferences("gridData", Context.MODE_APPEND);
        catid = p.getString("SelectedCatalogueIdFromGrid1", "");
        int clickedListPos = p.getInt("clickedPosition", 0);



        imageViewPreview = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
        imageThumbnails = new ArrayList<String>();
        imageFull = new ArrayList<String>();
        s1 = this.getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_APPEND);
        editor = s1.edit();


        Log.d("catidfnl", catid);
        numOfImagesInsidee = p.getInt("numberOfItemsSelectedFromGrid1", 0);

        Log.d("blingbling2", String.valueOf(numOfImagesInsidee));

        // adding downloaded images to arraylist
        for(int m=0;m<numOfImagesInsidee;m++){
            imageThumbnails.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"thumbImage" + catid + m+".png");
            imageFull.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"fullImage" + catid + m+".png");


            // imageFull.add("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "fullImage32.png");

        }

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


        // SubsamplingScaleImageView fullImage = new SubsamplingScaleImageView(ImageGallery.this);













        // code to display image in a horizontal strip starts here
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
        for (int i = 0; i < imageThumbnails.size(); i++) {
            imageView = new SubsamplingScaleImageView(this);
            imageView.setId(i);

            imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);

            // Picasso.with(this).load("file://"+imageThumbnails.get(i)).into(imageView);

            // imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            layout.addView(imageView);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = imageView.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = 200;
            params.height = 200;
            imageView.setLayoutParams(params);

            imageView.setZoomEnabled(false);
            imageView.setDoubleTapZoomScale(0);

            imageView.setImage(ImageSource.uri(imageThumbnails.get(0)));

            imageView.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {



                            imageView.setZoomEnabled(false);
                            imageViewPreview.setImage(ImageSource.uri(imageFull.get(view.getId())));
                            imageView.recycle();
                            imageViewPreview.recycle();

                        }
                    });
        }
        // code to display image in a horizontal strip ends here

        imageViewPreview.setZoomEnabled(false);

        /*imageViewPreview.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        imageViewPreview.setZoomEnabled(false);
                        stripeView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        gridFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        viewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                });*/

        imageViewPreview.setOnClickListener(new DoubleClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSingleClick(View v) {
                 Log.d("yo click", "single");
            }

            @Override
            public void onDoubleClick(View v) {
                Log.d("yo click", "double");
            }
        });


    }


    public abstract class DoubleClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        private static final long DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME_DELTA = 300;//milliseconds

        long lastClickTime = 0;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            long clickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (clickTime - lastClickTime < DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME_DELTA){
                onDoubleClick(v);
            } else {
                onSingleClick(v);
            }
            lastClickTime = clickTime;
        }

        public abstract void onSingleClick(View v);
        public abstract void onDoubleClick(View v);
    }




//    @Override
//    public void onBackPressed() {
//        Intent io = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
//        // clear the previous activity and start a new task
//        super.onBackPressed();
//        finish();
//        // System.gc();
//        // io.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
//        startActivity(io);
//    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_image_gallery, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
       /* private int[] mImages = new int[] {
                R.drawable.scroll3,
                R.drawable.scroll1,
                R.drawable.scroll2,
                R.drawable.scroll4

        };*/
        /* private String[] description=new String[]
                 {
                    "One","two","three","four"
                 };
 */
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            Log.i("Image List Size", "" + imageFull.size());
            return imageFull.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((SubsamplingScaleImageView) object);
        }




        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Context context = ImageGallery.this;

            SubsamplingScaleImageView fullImage = new SubsamplingScaleImageView(ImageGallery.this);

            // for placeholder
            // fullImage.setImage(ImageSource.resource(R.drawable.tan2x));

            if(!GridFragment2.isSelectedGrid2&&!ImageStripeFragment.isImageStripe) {
            imagePosition = position;
            fullImage.setImage(ImageSource.uri(imageFull.get(imagePosition)));

        }
       /* else if(!ImageStripeFragment.isImageStripe)
        {
            imagePosition = position;
            fullImage.setImage(ImageSource.uri(imageFull.get(imagePosition)));
        }
        else if(ImageStripeFragment.isImageStripe)
        {
            position=imagePosition;
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(imagePosition);
            fullImage.setImage(ImageSource.uri(imageFull.get(position)));
        }*/
            else
        {
            position=imagePosition;
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(imagePosition);
            fullImage.setImage(ImageSource.uri(imageFull.get(position)));


            //viewPager.removeAllViews();

        }

          // ImageView  imageViewPager = new ImageView(context);
           // ImageView imageViewPager = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
           // SubsamplingScaleImageView fullImage = new SubsamplingScaleImageView(ImageGallery.this);

            GridFragment2.isSelectedGrid2=false;
            ImageStripeFragment.isImageStripe=false;

           // Log.i("Image Resource", "" + ImageSource.uri(imageFull.get(position)));
        // imageViewPager.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFull.get(position)));
       // imageViewPager.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

            // fullImage.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(bmImg));

            //imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(imageFull.get(position)));
          /*int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
              R.dimen.padding_medium);
          imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);*/
            /*imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
            imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(imageFull.get(position)));

            if(position==3)
            {

            }*/
            //  Log.i("Image Position",""+position);
          /*text.setText(description[position]);
          Log.i("Text Position",""+position);*/
          /*switch(position)
          {

          case 0:
              String pos=String.valueOf(position);
            text.setText(pos);

              break;
          case 1:
              String pos1=String.valueOf(position);
              text.setText(pos1);
              break;
          case 2:
              String pos2=String.valueOf(position);
              text.setText(pos2);
              break;
          case 3:
              String pos3=String.valueOf(position);
              text.setText(pos3);
              break;
          }*/



            fullImage.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            if (toggleTopBar == false) {
                                // thumbnailButtons.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                thumbnailButtons.animate()
                                        .translationY(-2000)
                                        .setDuration(1000)
                                        .start();
                                toggleTopBar = true;
                            } else if (toggleTopBar == true) {
                                // thumbnailButtons.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                thumbnailButtons.animate()
                                        .translationY(0)
                                        .setDuration(1000)
                                        .start();
                                toggleTopBar = false;
                            }

                        }
                    });
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(fullImage, 0);

            return fullImage;
        }

       @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((SubsamplingScaleImageView) object);
        }
       /* @Override
        public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object o) {
            Log.d("DESTROY", "destroying view at position " + position);
            View view = (View) o;
            ((ViewPager) collection).removeView(view);
            view = null;
        }*/


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onBackPressed();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this ImageLoader Class

```
 public class ImageLoader {
MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
FileCache fileCache;
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
        .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
ExecutorService executorService;
Handler handler = new Handler();// handler to display images in UI thread
int stub_id;
int widht;

public ImageLoader(Context context, int stub_idx) {
    fileCache = new FileCache(context);
    executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    stub_id = stub_idx;
}

public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView, int widht, ProgressBar bar) {
    this.widht = widht;

    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
    if (bitmap != null)
    {
        bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    else {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView, widht, bar);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView, int w, ProgressBar bar) {
    PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView, bar);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p, w));
}

public  Bitmap getBitmap(String url, int w) {
    File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

    // from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f, w);
    if (b != null)
        return b;

    // from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                .openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        conn.disconnect();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f, w);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
            memoryCache.clear();
        return null;
    }
}

// decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f, int w) {
    try {
        // decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
        stream1.close();
        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = w;
        System.out.println("screen wdth " + widht);
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        System.out.println("image with === " + width_tmp);
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
        stream2.close();
        return bitmap;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(e.getMessage(), "");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

// Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad {
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public ProgressBar bar;

    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i, ProgressBar progressBar) {
        url = u;
        imageView = i;
        bar = progressBar;
    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    int w;

    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad, int w) {
        this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        this.w = w;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url, w);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            handler.post(bd);
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
    String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    return tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url);
}

// Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
        bitmap = b;
        photoToLoad = p;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if (bitmap != null)
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);

        photoToLoad.bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}
```

Then make new class for File cache

```
public class FileCache {

private File cacheDir;

public FileCache(Context context) {
    // Find the dir to save cached images
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir = new File(
                android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "LazyList");
    else
        //cacheDir = url.getCacheDir();
    if (!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
}

public File getFile(String url) {
    // I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the
    // demo.
    String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
    // Another possible solution (thanks to grantland)
    // String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url);
    File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
    return f;

}

public void clear() {
    File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
    if (files == null)
        return;
    for (File f : files)
        f.delete();
}

}
```

Then last make Memory cache class , all three seperatly class

```
public class MemoryCache {

private static final String TAG = "MemoryCache";
private Map<String, Bitmap> cache=Collections.synchronizedMap(
        new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(10,1.5f,true));//Last argument true for LRU ordering
private long size=0;//current allocated size
private long limit=1000000;//max memory in bytes

public MemoryCache(){
    //use 25% of available heap size
    setLimit(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/4);
}

public void setLimit(long new_limit){
    limit=new_limit;
    Log.i(TAG, "MemoryCache will use up to "+limit/1024./1024.+"MB");
}

public Bitmap get(String id){
    try{
        if(!cache.containsKey(id))
            return null;
        //NullPointerException sometimes happen here http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=78 
      return cache.get(id);
    }catch(NullPointerException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){
    try{
        if(cache.containsKey(id))
            size-=getSizeInBytes(cache.get(id));
        cache.put(id, bitmap);
        size+=getSizeInBytes(bitmap);
        checkSize();
    }catch(Throwable th){
        th.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void checkSize() {
    Log.i(TAG, "cache size="+size+" length="+cache.size());
    if(size>limit){
        Iterator<Entry<String, Bitmap>> iter=cache.entrySet().iterator();//least recently accessed item will be the first one iterated  
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            Entry<String, Bitmap> entry=iter.next();
            size-=getSizeInBytes(entry.getValue());
            iter.remove();
            if(size<=limit)
                break;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Clean cache. New size "+cache.size());
    }
}

public void clear() {
    try{
        //NullPointerException sometimes happen here http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=78 
        cache.clear();
        size=0;
    }catch(NullPointerException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

long getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if(bitmap==null)
        return 0;
    return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
}
```

Comment: shall i add the separte class or shall i change my full code?

Comment: u make new class then simply call like this

Comment: After Adding new class showing error.where i want to call that new class

Comment: you use this three class then pass like this ImageLoder loder = new ImageLoader(ctx, 1); then loader.DisplayImage(url, ivphoto, 400, bar); where bar is ProgressBar . ProgressBar add in your xml file    if satisfied then like my answer

Comment: Utils showing error and ImageLoder loder = new ImageLoader(ctx, 1); where want to call this class

Comment: yes i have utill class i added in adapter like this